# "Stack" is not found when coding Haskell in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs

While coding Haskell in emacs(stack installed with brew) on MacOS 10.12 I get the error:

Error while checking syntax automatically: (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "stack")

My config file .emacs contains the following:

```
(require 'package)
add-to-list
'package-archives
'("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'intero)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'intero-mode)
```

Running with emacs --debug-init gives no errors.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Comment: 1. issue `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and try it again (`--debug-init` only breaks into debugger on startup). 2. Are you sure `stack` is in the path? Did you try running it from terminal?

Comment: See this github issue: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/1300

Comment: @Yuri 1. Worked! I now get each time I change something the error:
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Symbol's function definition is void: haskell-completions-completion-at-point

2. It works in the terminal. However, I don't know how to verify if it's in the correct path

Comment: Check the link @elethan suggested.

Comment: Adding (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin/") to .emacs config file fixed the problem. Thanks @elethan

Comment: @JanjaapRee great! You should right that up as an answer for anyone else who might have the problem!

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to fix the problem by adding

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin/")
```

to the .emacs config file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) library; I had similar issues on OS X and this solved them for me.

Once the library is installed, put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

If you ever run emacs from the shell, it may be worth inserting the following instead:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```